# AngularJS Directive Wont Call Link After Compile and Insertion into DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, directive

For some reason the data on the myScope object isn't being passed and rendered. The directive inserts correctly via the append (static html from the template appears) but it's as if the digest hasn't ran to do the loop. I'd expect the link function to be called, which it isn't.

I've tried running $apply within a $timeout after insertion.

```
    .directive("slHyperlinkSelector", function () {
        return {
          templateUrl: "slHyperlinkSelector.html",
          restrict: "E",
          scope: {
              data: "=",
          },
          link: function (scope) {
              console.error('Is called');
          }
        };
    });

    $scope.$on('replaceView', function (event, builder) {

      var element = $element.find(".sl-account-canvas").children();
      var appendEl = builder(function () {

        $scope.maintain = false;
      });
      $scope.maintain = true;
      element.parent().append(appendEl);
      $timeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply();
      });
    });

    $rootScope.$broadcast('replaceView', function (closer) {

        var myScope = scope.$new(true);
        var destroy = function() {
          closer();
          myScope.$destroy();
        };

        myScope.data = {
          links: scope.formerNinos
            .map(function (formerNino) {

              return {
                textContent: formerNino.nino,
                onClick: function () { alert(formerNino.nino); destroy(); }
              };
            })
        };

       return $compile('<sl-hyperlink-selector data="data"></sl-hyperlink-selector>')(myScope);
     });


    (Template file below)

    <h2>Former National Insurance Numbers</h2>
    <ul class="sl-primary-card">
      <li ng-repeat="link in data.links">
        <h4><a href ng-click="link.onClick()">{{ link.textContent }}</a> 
   </h4>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I expect the directive to display several links.

Comment: You're using AngularJS aren't you?

Comment: Yes, apologies for the mistake.